# Correlated samples due to Metropolis algorithm

Tags: probability, simulation

The Wikipedia article about the Metropolis algorith notes one disadvantage as follows:

> The samples are correlated. Even though over the long term they do
>   correctly follow P(x), a set of nearby samples will be
>   correlated with each other and not correctly reflect the distribution.

So, can't one just randomize the array of collected samples at the end? Won't this get rid of the sample-to-sample cor-relatedness?

Comment: I do not fully understand your question? The fact that the simulations are correlated is due to the fact that the algorithm constructs a Markov chain. As mentioned on the Wikipedia page, a good way is to only select every $n$ th sample in the chain. To be more precise, you can make a correlogram which displays the correlation between successive samples and only select the samples which have a very low (almost none) correlation.

Comment: @Siron Thanks. What I mean is rather than throw away so many samples why not buffer the array & then randomize the sequence. Won't that get rid of any correlation?

Answer (score 1):

It gets rid of (most of) the local correlation, but in most applications that's irrelevant. Typically one wants to take an average over all samples, which doesn't depend on the order. The variance of the sample average is increased due to the correlation, and you can't change that by reordering.

However, if your application for some reason requires uncorrelated pairs or tuples of samples, then reordering will help. Even better than randomising the order, though, would be to deliberately pair values that are far apart, e.g. if you need pairs and take $2L$ samples, pair sample $j$ with sample $j+L$.

Comment: Thanks. Intuitively I see what you mean. But is the correlation, on average, of a `(j, j+L)` pair provably better than an ensemble of totally  random pairs?

Comment: @curious_cat: I haven't worked out a formal proof, but correlation should die off exponentially, so the average correlation here should be on the order of $\mathrm e^{-\lambda L}$, and in the other case it would be of the order of $\mathrm e^{-\lambda}/L$, since the probability for an adjacent pair to remain together is of order $\frac1L$. But depending on the application, the correlation time may be greater than $L$, so the exponential decay may not come into play.